# WordPress Page editor displaying incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, bridge

I am editing a page with WP Bakery Page Builder but somehow the settings changed. I am unable to edit the page with WP Bakery Page Builder again. A WordPress page editor is active that I am seeing first time. Anyone who has seen this before and has idea how I can revert back to WP Bakery Page Builder?

[Incorrect page editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuewJ.png)

This is how it should look like:
[correct page editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtjpH.png)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You're using WordPress 5.0 and it has many changes. Main big change is the editor. So, you can't now longer use former classic editor as WordPress moved to block-based editor. You need to install and activate https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ to get back to former editor version. Please follow this article for more info https://nerodev.com/how-to-use-wordpress-classic-editor/

Comment: Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665947/how-to-use-classic-editor-with-wordpress-5-0/53665948#53665948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, you have upgraded to WordPress 5.0 and many plugin that custom editor will may not work correctly with the new editor version called [Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/).

## Easy way

...is install, activate Classic Editor (https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) plugin and everything become "normal".

If you still seeing Block Editor, click **Switch to Classic editor** like the screenshot below.

[image]

Or click to **Classic editor** when you are on Posts list page.

[image]

## Harder way

Downgrade your WordPress site to 4.9.5 will make anything be fine without losing any data.

Comment: Can't accept `Downgrade` option. You just need to use `Classic Editor` plugin.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day!