# How to use Classic Editor with WordPress 5.0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, updates, auto-update

Recently I updated the WordPress version to new 5.0 version. After the update it is showing me a different editor than I worked before.

But I want to access previous editor I worked with. How can I get back to former WordPress editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently WordPress introduces its version 5.0. With this version WordPress has introduces the block-based editor instead of using former classic editor.

**How to get back to former editor?**

You need to install and activate [Classic Editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/). This will add new `Classic Editor` editor option. For more details about installing a plugin, please refer this guide on [how to install a plugin in WordPress](https://nerodev.com/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-wordpress/).

[image]

To get back to the former editor you need to click on `Classic Editor` every-time.

It'll bring you to the former classic editor. Here is a great article on [WordPress Classic Editor in WordPress 5.0](https://nerodev.com/how-to-use-wordpress-classic-editor/).

**Drawback**

At the moment this classic editor feature supports till 2021 according to the developers. You need to learn and move forward with this new block-based editor as it is trying to bring you all to a new arena.

Happy learning ahead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are three main strategies.

1. **Fall back to the former editor**. The most simple way is to use [ClassicEditor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/). It solves the current problem immidiately and require no additional actions. But this solution is temporary because plugin support is limited to 2022 (for now). This strategy is ok if you use WP for your own, don't need a long-term support (e.g. for clients sites) and feel comfortable with latest WordPress development direction in general.
2. **Migrate to ClassicPress.** If you look for a full alternative (WordPress without Gutenberg at all) or do not feel comfortable with latest WP updates, consider using [ClassicPress](https://www.classicpress.net/roadmap/) instead. This is a fork (a clone of native WP v 4.9) with some additional features. It tends to reduce excessive functionality making WP more suitable for professional use. And it uses Classic Editor by default (Gutenberg files are totally removed from the core).
3. **"Freeze" your WP version.** You can use Wordpress version 4.9 and avoid any updates forever. In this case you will probably use some plugins like [Disable All Wordpress Updates](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/) or similar. Pros and cons are rather obvious, but keep in mind that you have to "freeze" plugins versions as well. This is not a proper solution for a growing modern site.

You can find some additional arguments and detailes in [this discussion](https://forums.classicpress.net/t/different-anti-gutenberg-strategies/952).

Answer (score 0):

You should install "Classic Editor" plugin to use classic editor